# Per-action equivalent of load_and_authorize_resource through: - CanCanCan + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, nested-resources, cancancan

In the [CanCanCan Documentation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki), it shows what the per-action equivalent of `load_and_authorize_resource` is ([Controller Authorization Example](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Controller-Authorization-Example)), and how to handle nested resources using the `load_and_authorize_resource` method  ([Nested Resources](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Nested-Resources)), but I was not able to find the per-action equivalent of the `load_and_authorize_resource` *and* load a parent resource.

Is there a per-action equivalent to:

```rb
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :project
  load_and_authorize_resource :task, :through => :project
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
authorize! :read, @project
@task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
authorize! :action, @task
```